# Глобальная переменная для определенного чата

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу telegram бота на Python с помощью `pyTelegramBotAPI` и мне нужно сделать авторизацию пользователей по ключу доступа. Нужно сделать, чтобы когда пользователь вводил ключ доступа переменная auth менялась с `false` на `true`, только для того пользователя который ввел ключ, а не для всех.

Как это реализовать?

```py
auth = 'false'
def handle_message(message):
    if message.text == '/key ....':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы были авторизованны для бота, ждите ставок.\nУдачи!')
        global auth
        auth = 'true'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, auth)
    elif message.text == '/key ....':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы были авторизованны для бота, ждите ставок.\nУдачи!')
        auth = 'true'
    elif message.text == '/key ....':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы были авторизованны для бота, ждите ставок.\nУдачи!')
        auth = 'true'
    elif message.text == '/key ....':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы были авторизованны для бота, ждите ставок.\nУдачи!')
        auth = 'true'
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно')
        auth = 'false'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['auth'])
def handle_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, auth)
```

Когда пользователь вводит ключ доступа, он срабатывает на всех участников, а нужно для того, кто ввел этот ключ доступа.

Comment: Глобальные переменные - зло. Никогда их не используйте.

Comment: А как мне это реализовать без них?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам переменная auth?
Если Вы заранее знаете какие ключи доступа будут вводить пользователи просто сделайте проверку на совпадение

```
code = '5555'


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'введи код')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, auth)


def auth(message):
    print('auth')
    print(message.chat.id)
    print(message.text)
    if message.text == code:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'добро пожаловать в клуб')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'вы кто такой?')
```

или я что-то упустил в Вашем вопросе?